# Counting words in the array - How can I query with mongo?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

```
"sourceList": [
        {
           "source" : "hello world, how are you?",
           "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
        },
        {
           "source" : "hello world, I am fine",
           "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
        },
        {
           "source" : "Is it raining?",
           "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
        }
]
```

Total words in `hello world, how are you?` = 5, in `hello world, I am fine` = 5, and in `Is it raining?`= 3.

Thus the total number of words = `13`

Is there a mongo query to do this calculation? I could do this using javascript, but is there a direct way to query via mongo?

**EDIT**

---

Is there a way I can do this query across the documents? For documents obeying specific criteria, I want to run a similar calculation with an added constraint, that words of duplicate sentences are not counted twice. For example,

Document - 1

```
"sourceList": [
    {
       "source" : "hello world, how are you?",
       "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
    },
    {
       "source" : "hello world, I am fine",
       "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
    },
    {
       "source" : "Is it raining?",
       "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
    }
]
```

Document - 2

```
  "sourceList": [
    {
       "source" : "hello world, how are you?",
       "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
    },
    {
       "source" : "hello world, I am fine",
       "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
    },
    {
       "source" : "Is it raining?",
       "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
    }
]
```

Here the count still remains the same. The reason being, sentences are exactly same in both the documents. But if we combine Document 1 + Document 3 (given as follows)

```
"sourceList": [
    {
       "source" : "Look at the beautiful tiger!",
       "_id" : ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
    }
]
```

The count would come as 13 + 5 (document 3) = 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can do that with the help of powerful aggregate framework.

[mongo play-ground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JdYzNiFDnY6)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$sourceList" //For each array element
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "sp": {
        $split: [
          "$sourceList.source", //split by spaces
          " "
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sizes": {
        "$size": "$sp". //count the words in each array
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$sizes" //group by id to reverse unwind and add the sizes
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Update:**

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aGVYqEGBSfJ)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$sourceList"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "sp": {
        $split: [
          "$sourceList.source",
          " "
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sizes": {
        "$size": "$sp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$sizes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

For huge collections, you may need to use `allowDiskUse` but it is very heavy operation for larger collections.

**Update:**

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1kxFWkSU1GP)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$sourceList"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "sp": {
        $split: [
          "$sourceList.source",
          " "
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "elements": {
        $addToSet: "$sp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$elements"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sizes": {
        "$size": "$elements"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$sizes"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this across the document collection? I have created an edit.

Comment: I will update the answer. You should mention at the first time :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Actually learnt something new today thanks to you. In my opinion this is when mongodb and other db really outshines firebase in supporting statistical analysis at the server side.

Comment: The updated query will also consider the word count from duplicate strings. For example, https://mongoplayground.net/p/up4wukJWCjc will output the total word count as `21` but it had to be `18`, since `Is it raining?` is repeated in both the documents.

Comment: ok, duplicates has to be removed? - duplicate words or duplicate statements?

Comment: Yes, duplicate sentences must be counted only once.

Comment: I am trying `db.getCollection('MC').find({url: /some-domain/}).aggregate( .. )` and it says `db.getCollection(...).find(...).aggregate is not a function`

Comment: You should not mix both. i,e find and aggregate. Remove `find({url: /some-domain/})`

Comment: I want to operate this on a collection of documents. That is why I added `find`. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to add $match as first stage `{$match :{url:""}} `

Comment: I added it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/oaoQQeKJ2rQ . Could you confirm? I want to do a pattern match

Comment: How can I pass multiple delimiters for `$translations.source`? I want to first split by `\n` and then by `" "`

Comment: I request you to add another question as your main query solved related to this post

Comment: I have asked a related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260572/incorrect-count-from-aggregation-query . Could you help answer this