# Incorrect count from aggregation query

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

In the following document collection, I am trying to find the total words of unique sentences. The total words must come out as 5 (hello\nworld, how are you?) + 5 (hello world, I am fine) + 3(Is it raining?) + 5(Look at the beautiful tiger!) = 18

```
[
    {
        "sourceList": [
        {
            "source": "hello\nworld, how are you?",
            "_id": ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
        },
        {
            "source": "hello world, I am fine",
            "_id": ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
        },
        {
            "source": "Is it raining?",
            "_id": ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sourceList": [
        {
            "source": "Look at the beautiful tiger!",
            "_id": ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
        },
        {
            "source": "Is it raining?",
            "_id": ObjectId("5f0eb9946db57c0007841153")
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

But with the below query

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$sourceList"
    },
    {
        $project: {
        "sp": {
            $split: [
                "$sourceList.source",
                "\n"
            ],
            $split: [
                "$sourceList.source",
                " "
            ]
        }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "elements": {
                $addToSet: "$sp"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$elements"
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "sizes": {
                "$size": "$elements"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
                "$sum": "$sizes"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

it gives as `17`. What could be the reason for this? I am first trying to split by `\n` and then by `space`

**EDIT**

I am trying to find word count for unique sentences and total unique sentences.

Comment: Are you looking for total unique sentences or total unique words or both?

Comment: @Gibbs Total Unique Sentences and Total Unique words

Comment: And you are expecting 4 and 18?

Comment: @Gibbs Yes..... I scrape a website, insert all text into mongo. After that I need to calculate total word count for unique sentences and also total unique sentences.

Comment: @Gibbs Please note that I am attempting word count for unique sentences and not unique word count for unique sentences

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that here:

```
"sp": {
    $split: [
        "$sourceList.source",
        "\n"
    ],
    $split: [
        "$sourceList.source",
        " "
    ]
}
```

only the second `$split` gets executed by MongoDB and it returns `hello\nworld` as one string. There's no such "cascade" syntax, since it's simply the same JSON key `$split` so last wins.

In order to fix that you can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to apply `$split` by whitespace on an array of split by `\n` values:

```
{
    $project: {
        "sp": {
            $reduce: {
                input: { $split: [ "$sourceList.source", "\n" ] },
                initialValue: [],
                in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", { $split: [ "$$this", " " ] } ] }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_3poiPMovZl)

Comment: How is your query different from one posted by @gibbs? I am trying to find out word count of unique sentences and also the total unique sentences

Comment: @Amanda mine was added first and my goal was to answer why the number is different than `18` which was your initial question. Not sure what happened then :-)

Comment: Also added in the edit, I am trying to find word count for unique sentences and total unique sentences. Does this query give the word count for unique sentences?

Comment: Yep, @micki is correct. He resolved your primary problem. As per your comment, I resolved you lr both count issues. I wish I could approve this answer :)

Comment: @Gibbs there's enough reputation for both of us in this question :-)

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments and addition to @micki's answer and my previous answer,

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D-ZtJ3zrspG)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$sourceList"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "sp": {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $split: [
              "$sourceList.source",
              "\n"
            ]
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $split: [
                  "$$this",
                  " "
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "elements": {
        $addToSet: "$sp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "unique_sen": {
        "$size": "$elements"
      },
      "elements": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$elements"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sizes": {
        "$size": "$elements"
      },
      "unique_sen": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "unique_count": {
        "$sum": "$sizes"
      },
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "unique_count": 1,
      "unique_sen": {
        $first: "$data.unique_sen"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Update:**

You don't need to escape in the query.

[play](https://mongoplayzground.net/p/O0TjXSKESZs)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "url": "https://www.rootsresource.in"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$translations"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "sp": {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $split: [
              "$translations.source",
              "\n"
            ]
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $split: [
                  "$$this",
                  " "
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "elements": {
        $addToSet: "$sp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "unique_sen": {
        "$size": "$elements"
      },
      "elements": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$elements"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sizes": {
        "$size": "$elements"
      },
      "unique_sen": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "unique_count": {
        "$sum": "$sizes"
      },
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "unique_count": 1,
      "unique_sen": {
        $first: "$data.unique_sen"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**UPDATE:**

Above query works from mongo 4.4 - $first is available in project from 4.4

For older versions.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      url: "https://www.rootsresource.in"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$translations"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "sp": {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $split: [
              "$translations.source",
              "\n"
            ]
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $split: [
                  "$$this",
                  " "
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "elements": {
        $addToSet: "$sp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "unique_sen": {
        "$size": "$elements"
      },
      "elements": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$elements"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sizes": {
        "$size": "$elements"
      },
      "unique_sen": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "unique_count": {
        "$sum": "$sizes"
      },
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "unique_count": 1,
        unique_sen: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data.unique_sen", 0 ] }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Tying this directly in mongo gives an error. Screenshot https://ibb.co/x1tnFL9

Comment: [play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D-ZtJ3zrspG) - could you update the query with play which you are trying?

Comment: It provides when you remove match. Match error is different than the one in the image.

Comment: Not sure why. But I am running the query inside Robo3T

Comment: It says `Unrecognized expression '$first`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219249/discussion-between-amanda-and-gibbs).

Comment: Now it says `Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'url'`.

Comment: Could you see why https://mongoplayground.net/p/615caKudprT is not working on playground?

Comment: This is the exact query I am trying

Comment: Gives `unrecognized expression first`

Comment: This gives "zero records"

Comment: You check the collection field names whether it is matching. Or add a play?. I used collection name as test. You many have another collection.

Comment: Works fine now. The count is same as earlier.

Comment: Are you saying some count issues?

Comment: Is there a resource you could recommend to learn about mongo aggregations'

Comment: I am not sure. My count through javascript is more by 13K

Comment: Documentation is the correct source. As I told you earlier, always ask specific problem. Here your count mismatch is resolved. Query has match condition. Note that. And I suggest you to upvote and approve eligible answers. I suggest you to try out to learn

Comment: I suggest you to delete unnecessary comments also :) happy learning